# Need to make the code works faster since I need to train large data

Tags: python-3.x, performance, concurrency, multiprocessing, large-data

I am new to multiprocessing and do not have that much coding experience in python. I have to train a large amount of data for the code listed below.  I train the data and save them in the Count min sketch for other purposes. Here is the code :

```
class abc:

    def __init__(self, number_of_grams, number_of_models=4, threshold_pruning=40, cms_depth=7, cms_width=4530470,
                 threshold_detection=40):
        self.number_of_grams = number_of_grams
        self.number_of_models = number_of_models
        self.threshold_pruning = threshold_pruning
        self.cms_depth = cms_depth
        self.cms_width = cms_width
        self.threshold_detection = threshold_detection
        self.prototype_models = []

    colorama.init()

    def model_initialization(self, initialization_file):
        """Initializing prototype models with random samples.

        Model initialization takes random packets from a file equals to number of models. From each packet, n-grams
        are generated and then added to the prototype models which serves as a cluster head and used during training.
        """
        if self.prototype_models:
            print(Fore.BLUE + "Models are not empty, skipping initialization." + Style.RESET_ALL)
            return
        packet_reader = rdpcap(initialization_file)
        random_samples = random.sample(range(len(packet_reader)), self.number_of_models)
        for model in range(self.number_of_models):
            init_packet = packet_reader[random_samples[model]].original
            prototype_model = CountMinSketch(width=self.cms_width, depth=self.cms_depth)
            counter_y, norm_y = self.normalized_count(init_packet)
            for ngram, count in counter_y.items():
                prototype_model.add(ngram, (count / norm_y))
            self.prototype_models.append(prototype_model)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f'Model initialization is complete with file {initialization_file}.' + Style.RESET_ALL)

    def normalized_count(self, packet):
        """Generating n-grams of a packet, counting them and normalizing their count."""
        gram_list = [packet[i:i + self.number_of_grams].hex() for i in range(len(packet) - self.number_of_grams + 1)]
        count_grams = defaultdict(int)
        for gram in gram_list:
            count_grams[gram] += 1
        square_sum = sum(count ** 2 for count in count_grams.values())
        return count_grams, math.sqrt(square_sum)

    def complete_training(self, dataset_training_path, saved_model_path):
        """Complete training has model initialization and model training modules.

        It takes the training dataset path and the path to save the trained model as parameters.
        """
        all_files = glob.glob(dataset_training_path + "*")
        print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + f'All the training files are {all_files}' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        saved_model_path = saved_model_path
        random_file = random.choice(all_files)
        self.model_initialization(random_file)
        self.model_training(all_files, saved_model_path)

    def model_training(self, all_files, saved_model_path):
        """Model training trains the models and saves the trained model for detection.

        All the files received during training are read and each packet
        is assigned to the different models based on the similarity
        score calculated between initialized model and the packet.
        Each model is named as a cluster and has single packet
        after the initialization phase. After each packet is assigned to the
         different models, the cluster size increases accordingly.
        """
        clusters_sizes = [1 for i in range(self.number_of_models)]
        print(Fore.GREEN + "Start Training. This may take a while "
                           "(minutes, up to hours, days, months!)" + Style.RESET_ALL)

        with open('infofile', mode='w') as result_file:
            result_writer = csv.writer(result_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            result_writer.writerow(['File Name', 'Packet Index', 'Model Number'])
            max_lines = 200000
            lines_written = 0
            max_lines_reached = False

            for file in all_files:
                packet_reader = rdpcap(file)
                print(Fore.GREEN + f"Training with file: {packet_reader}" + Style.RESET_ALL)
                index_packet = 0

                # Iterating over all the packets
                for packet in packet_reader:
                    index_packet += 1
                    packet = packet.original
                    winning_cluster_index = self.assign_to_cluster(packet, clusters_sizes)
                    if lines_written < max_lines:
                        result_writer.writerow([file, index_packet, winning_cluster_index])
                        lines_written += 1
                        if lines_written == max_lines:
                            max_lines_reached = True
                    elif not max_lines_reached:
                        result_writer.writerow([file, index_packet, winning_cluster_index])

        print(Fore.GREEN + f'The total number of packets on the clusters are {clusters_sizes}.' + Style.RESET_ALL)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'Training is finished.' + Style.RESET_ALL)

        for count, model in enumerate(self.prototype_models):
            model.export(f'{saved_model_path}/model{count}.cms')
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'All the models are saved to the disk.' + Style.RESET_ALL)

    def similarity_score(self, model, counter_x, norm_x):
        """Calculating similarity score of a packet for each model."""
        proximity_score = 0
        for n_gram, count in counter_x.items():
            proximity_score += model.check(n_gram) * (count / norm_x)
        return proximity_score

    def assign_to_cluster(self, packet, clusters_sizes):
        """Assigning a packet to a cluster by finding out the closest cluster."""
        counter_x, norm_x = self.normalized_count(packet)
        sim_scores = np.array([self.similarity_score(model, counter_x, norm_x) / clusters_sizes[i] for i, model in
                               enumerate(self.prototype_models)])
        winning_cluster_index = argmax(sim_scores)
        for n_gram, count in counter_x.items():
            self.prototype_models[winning_cluster_index].add(n_gram, count / norm_x)
        clusters_sizes[winning_cluster_index] += 1
        return winning_cluster_index
```

I have thousands of network packets to process and assign them to the count min sketch. I profiled the code to see where most of the time is gone.

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.006    0.006   80.191   80.191 copy_without bloom.py:62(complete_training)
        1    0.061    0.061   79.101   79.101 copy_without bloom.py:74(model_training)
     9999    0.419    0.000   77.249    0.008 copy_without bloom.py:128(assign_to_cluster)
     9999    0.110    0.000   64.278    0.006 copy_without bloom.py:130(<listcomp>)
    39996    1.613    0.000   64.169    0.002 copy_without bloom.py:120(similarity_score)
  1567480    2.268    0.000   55.820    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:324(check)
  1567480   27.174    0.000   40.181    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:333(check_alt)
  1959486    2.409    0.000   16.550    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:246(hashes)
  1959486    4.361    0.000   13.741    0.000 probables/hashes.py:119(default_xxh3_64)
   392006    0.604    0.000   10.638    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:257(add)
    49999    2.212    0.000    8.404    0.000 copy_without bloom.py:53(normalized_count)
  1959486    4.963    0.000    7.581    0.000 probables/hashes.py:130(<listcomp>)
   392006    2.499    0.000    6.855    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:267(add_alt)
  1567480    6.776    0.000    6.776    0.000 ountminsketch/countminsketch.py:343(<listcomp>)
    49999    3.471    0.000    4.618    0.000 copy_without bloom.py:55(<listcomp>)
   392006    2.465    0.000    3.278    0.000 countminsketch/countminsketch.py:276(<listcomp>)
 13716402    2.618    0.000    2.618    0.000 {method 'intdigest' of 'xxhash.xxh3_64' objects}
  1567480    2.125    0.000    2.125    0.000 {built-in method numpy.arange}
  1567480    1.822    0.000    1.822    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    49999    0.363    0.000    1.511    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
```

I am using xxh3_64 hash function which is one of the fastest hash function. This result is just for a file with 1.7MB. Since I have to train around 170 GB data, it will take many days.

How can I make the code faster? Should I use multiprocessing or not? If yes for which function I should use it. If multiple processes try to read and write the same Countminsketch it will create a race condition. I know locks can be used but I want solid theoretical approach which part I should use multiprocessing and how and as well as help in the code to make the code faster and train as fast as possible . I could not fix the problem with multiprocessing pickle. So, I am using pathos.multiprocessing library. If anyone can help me please you can contact me personally as well. I tried a lot without clear approaches and failed it. This has been a headache for me and wasted many days.

Comment: Python is a mess for parallel computing (and even for high performance). Multiprocessing is mainly useful for embarrassingly parallel computations and when the communication overhead is not to high, not to mention the time to create the heavy processes. Multithreading is nearly useless for computation that are not latency bound (eg. IO bound) due to the GIL. This is not gonna be better any time soon as long as the GIL is there. In fact, Python as not been design with parallelism in mind. It is meant to run scripts and glue code that often do not need to be cleverly parallelized.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerome. what would you suggest @JérômeRichard?

Comment: For advanced parallel computing, I advise not Python but a native language (eg. C/C++). This can also help for sequential performance. Cython might help to start with but AFAIK the parallelism model is too basic in Cython (still you can run multiple threads without having the GIL to consider). Note that AFAIK you cannot have race condition with multiprocessing because objects are copied+serialized on each process (which is also why makes CPython parallel codes are slow). Objects can be shared but AFAIK this cause a big lock to be used combined with the serialization overhead (very slow).

Comment: In language like C/C++, OpenMP can be used to easily parallelize codes. That being said, with a significant part of your application spent in functions called `check` and `check_alt` I wonder if the code is not bound by useless check and so if you could just pick a faster implementation of `CountMinSketch` at the expense of a less safe one. Still, native library tends to favour speed over safety (unless explicitly requested).

Comment: Here is the check and check_alt function:

```
    def check(self, key: KeyT) -> int:
        return self.check_alt(self.hashes(key))

    def check_alt(self, hashes: HashResultsT) -> int:
        bins = [(val % self.width) + (i * self.width) for i, val in enumerate(hashes)]
        return self.__query_method(sorted([self._bins[i] for i in bins]))
```

Comment: Basically check is calling check_alt and check alt function calculate the bin and sort the items from the bin.

Comment: It seems really not efficient to do that in pure-Python since the code is *interpreted* (not to mention a modulus is a pretty slow operation). Interpreted code are generally several order of magnitude slower than native code (unless most of the time is spent in efficient native functions)